# Picking Date format string from user locale

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using a Dojo DateTextBox in my website which takes date format in form of contstraint like `"dd-mm-yyyy"` etc. I need to pick the date format string of the visitor's locale and pass it to this DateTextBox to display the date in local format. I do not need a way to get the formatted date but to get the format string.

Comment: why not just set the visitor's locale in data-dojo-config?  Let Dojo pick the appropriate format for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(["dojo/i18n", "dojo/date/locale"], function(i18n) {

    var defaultLocale = i18n.normalizeLocale();
    var bundle = i18n.getLocalization("dojo.cldr", "gregorian", defaultLocale);

    // all available formats
    console.dir(bundle);

    // some of them
    console.log(bundle['dateFormat-full']);
    console.log(bundle['dateFormat-long']);
    console.log(bundle['dateFormat-medium']);
    console.log(bundle['dateFormat-short']);
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/4ZDCv/

**Alternatively** require directly the localization bundle via `dojo/i18n` plugin:

```
require(["dojo/i18n!dojo/cldr/nls/gregorian"], function(gregorian) {

    console.dir(gregorian); // all available formats

    console.log(gregorian['dateFormat-full']);
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/jJVEU/

**Edit:** `dijit/form/DateTextBox` handles locale itself, therefore it's likely all you need is setting `formatLength`:

```
<input
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox"
    data-dojo-props="constraints: { formatLength: 'long' }"
/>
```

An example how it works with multiple locales on the page: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/PhHwg/

Answer (score 0):

Try this (reference: [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var d = new Date();

var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

curr_date = (curr_date < 10 ? "0" + curr_date : curr_date);
curr_month = (curr_month < 10 ? "0" + curr_month : curr_month);

var formatted_date = "" + curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year;

</script>
```